# How do i get a specific range for "List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>"?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, maps, sudoku

I want to write a Sudoku App for which i have a List in a List of Maps to highlight and show the integers in the playfield.

My list looks like this:

```
  List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> output = [
    [
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
    ],
    [
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      {'integer': '', 'color': Colors.purple},
      ...
```

So i want to change the color of a specific Area. I have tried some googlin and came up with this and some variations:

```
  selectField(indexBlock, index) {
    output[indexBlock][index]['color'] = Colors.white;
    output[indexBlock].getRange(0, 8).['color'] = Colors.purpleAccent; // this part with getRange is not working like i want it to
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: i won't call this an answer, its more of a hack, but you could create a function that would loop other the range...

Comment: `output[indexBlock].getRange(0, 8).['color'] = Colors.purpleAccent;` should properly be: `output[indexBlock].getRange(0, 8).forEach((e) => e['color'] = Colors.purpleAccent);`